# Visual Studio 2015 tells me that dependencies are not met although one is not for Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm, npm-install, gulp-browser-sync

I use Visual Studio 2015 with gulp via npm. 
I installed the package `browser-sync` which relies on `chokidar.fsevents`. As I understand this dependency is only needed on MacOSX so installation fails with this error:

```
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
```

I understand this is only a warning and no error. But VS tells me that dependencies are not met:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: I got the same issue with you. This issue could be resolved on Browser-sync official document: https://browsersync.io/docs/#windows-users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the Web Tools for VS. It appears to be due to the fact that "fsevents" is listed in both "dependencies" and "optionalDependencies" for chokidar. The npm documentation says "optionalDependencies" should override in this case, but VS's logic doesn't honor that rule.

You can ignore the warning, or edit chokidar's package.json to remove the dependency.

I've logged the bug against the Web Tools. We will try to fix this in a future release.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the bug tracker issue?

Answer (score -1):

The only fix working for me is to edit the package.json of chokidar, removing the fsevents dependencies. I moved them in a new element (to have a trace):

```
"removed_dependecies": {
    "fsevents": "^1.0.0"
},
```